# jQuery stop() in MooTools

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mootools, porting

I'm interested in porting a project from jquery to mootools to learn this library.

Everything has been done, but I'm missing a single line that makes the behaviour of my project a little unexpected. Here is the line:

```
slideInfo.stop(true, true);
```

In jQuery this line stops the currently-running animation of the element, with the first parameter indicating to remove queued animation as well, and the second to indicate to complete the current animation immediately.

I've been looking into MooTools docs, but I cannot a method to port this behaviour. Is there anyone with MooTools experience able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into MooTools FX class. This handle a lot of the animation components http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx I think cancel() is what you may need